# Разделение запятой в PHP нескольких переменных

Tags: php

Есть условные переменные, которые нужно записать разделив запятыми в одну строку. Как это лучше сделать, чтоб при изменении наличия значений запятые не оставались на местах?

Пример:

```
<?php echo $val1 . ', ' . $val2 . ', ' . $val3 ?>
```

Подозреваю, что первая рекомендация будет слепить массив и использовать `implode`, но, может ещё есть варианты? Так как всё равно требуются условия, чтоб проверить наличие каждой переменной при создании массива.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$a = 'a';
$b = 'b';
$c = null;
$d = 'd';

echo foo($a, $b, $c, $d /* и т.д. */);


function foo(... $args): string
{
    return join(', ', array_filter($args));
}
```

---

```
Результат: a, b, d
```

Comment: Супер. Спасибо!